# Getting 403 Forbidden: Access denied error when sending client certificate on some clients

Tags: iis-7.5, http-status-code-403, client-certificates

We have an ASP.NET MVC web application where we use digital signatures for both authorization and signing purposes. So in the SSL Settings of the website I've chosen to Require client certificates. I've also chosen to require SSL. But with some clients I have a problem with 403 Forbidden: Access denied error. If I choose to Ignore the Client Certificates the error goes away. Again, this error occurs only with couple of clients, the rest can connect OK.

The IIS version is 7.5

You might wonder the set up of those problematic and the rest clients in the network: There are two routers, A and B. Some clients connect to A and some to B. The above problem occurs on both cases. So nothing like the problematic clients are connected to router A or B.

Answer (score 0):

Had this error for awhile not to long ago, unfortunately it could be anything in the setup. I'll take a shot in the dark and the client is using the machine name? and not the pre made user used for the service.

Comment: What do you mean by "client is using the machine name?"